# What is the maximum number of seed slots you can get in Plants vs. Zombies?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies

I bought the 9th seed slot from Crazy Dave's shop, and now it says sold out. Is that it, or can I unlock a 10th seed slot from somewhere?

Comment: In my game, after I bought the 9 seed slot, Dave replaced it with a 10 seed slot. I'm not sure if that's the max as it's insanely expensive ($80,000). I will have to kill a lot of zombies to afford that to find out if there are a bigger seed slots.

Comment: 10 seed slots is the max on the PC version, at least. It's quite expensive - $80,000. However, you will probably want it if you replay the campaign with Dave's 3 randomly selected plants.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As per the Plants vs zombies [wiki](http://plantsvszombies.wikia.com/wiki/Crazy_Dave%27s_Twiddydinkies):

> Extra Seed Slot ten - $80,000 (unavailable on iOS, Mobiles with Samsung bada OS, DS, and Android because the screen is not big enough to fit it)

If we think about the size of the screen, this may also be why it is unavailable on the Windows phone version.

Comment: That's... an odd explanation for the missing feature.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming it's the same as other Plants vs Zombies games, 9 is the maximum number of seed slots you can have.

Comment: Based on the Android version I would say this is correct.  There are UI difference from the PC version but gameplay is the same.

Comment: Other comments here mention that it's not the same as _all_ other ports of the game.

Answer (score 2):

You can get 10 seed slots on the Xbox 360.

Answer (score 1):

You can get up to 10 slots on plants vs zombies. I personally wish there was more because I am gaining so much money so quickly.

Comment: Maybe explain how you get the 10th one since the asker seems to not know how.